# How To Shrink Categorized Column on xPage

Tags: css, xpages

Here is my simple xPage (bootstrap theme) with view control

### My code:

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanelFileResource" viewStyle="width:100%" var="rowData">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="File Resources"></xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:viewColumn id="viewColumn1" columnName="FileEntryCategory">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader1" value="File entry category"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
    <xp:viewColumn columnName="FileEntryTitle" id="viewColumn2">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader id="viewColumnHeader2" value="Title"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
    </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

And the very first column is categorized. But how to shrink it (see picture above)? Just setting the column width doesn't help. It wraps the category name. 
And also how to add some padding to the category icon and name. I don't wanna use just the formula like this `"  " + columnValue`

### Screenshoot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the column header for your categorized column is one easy fix.

Howard

Answer (score 1):

Controlling the column width: see Howard's answer; for completeness: simply remove any texxt from the view Column Header's `label` element.

There are many ways to add some padding to the Collapse / Expand images which are child elements to a `button` element. I usually add a style class to the view column, so that I can properly address the child elements (there's no direct way to add style classes to the image or button elements). Then add some css code to the style sheet as in

```
.viewColCategoryClass button {padding-right:5px;}
```

Comment: This does help to add a padding to the icon: .xspBootstrapRowIcon {padding-left:10px;}